# E-step of the stochastic approximation EM

Tags: expectation-maximization

I am reading the paper: [Convergence of a stochastic approximation version of the EM algorithm](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-27/issue-1/Convergence-of-a-stochastic-approximation-version-of-the-EM-algorithm/10.1214/aos/1018031103.full) to implement this algorithm for a probability model I already have. In p. 3, the paper summarises the algorithm as follows.

[image]

I am stuck at the E (or S) step in this algorithm. In a typical EM setup, one maximizes the integral $$Q(\theta)= \int \log p(x,y |\theta) p(x|y,\theta) dx$$
In here, this integral is estimated via the samples simulated from the posterior. I understand this. But, what I do not understand is: Do authors propose to 'update' the cost function? If so, how can we maximize the new $Q$? May be I am missing a very obvious thing and can not see how to implement this algorithm (I do not understand updating the 'cost').

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an EM, $Q_k(\theta)$ is the result of the $k$th E step. It is not a classical cost function, but rather an approximation of the true target likelihood function, which you maximize in the M step.

There proposed algorithm is simply an EM where the E step cannot be computed analytically so it is estimated using Monte Carlo methods.

You can do the maximization in the M step using nay appropriate optimization scheme appropriate to the characteristics of Q. Say, analytically if Q permits it, or numerically if necessary. Note however, that as in any EM, you actually don't need to maximize Q, but rather just find a $theta$ that improves on the initial values.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder about, at the $k$-th step, what would $Q_{k-1}(\theta)$? So, to find the maximizer of the (6) (in the figure), do I have to use the samples of the 'previous' iteration? I suppose, my question is not asked in a clear way. Sorry.

Comment: Once you have computed (6), it is a mere function of $\theta$ you can optimize.